# How to use tailwindjs with vite and vue2?

Tags: vuejs2, tailwind-css, vite

How to use tailwindjs with vite and vue2?
Someone say just install these dependencies:

```
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.9",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "postcss": "^7",    
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
```

and import in my main.js

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"
```

but the error come out:

```
../../../node_modules/purgecss/lib/purgecss.esm.js:1:7: error: No matching export in "browser-external:fs" for import "access"
../../../node_modules/purgecss/lib/purgecss.esm.js:1:19: error: No matching export in "browser-external:fs" for import "readFile"
../../../node_modules/purgecss/lib/purgecss.esm.js:1:33: error: No matching export in "browser-external:fs" for import "constants"
../../../node_modules/purgecss/lib/purgecss.esm.js:1:175: error: No matching export in "browser-external:util" for import "promisify"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont import the tailwind in main.js directly and it works this way:

Install dependencies:

```
"dependencies":{
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.9",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
}
```

My index.css is :

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

and my postcss.config.js

```
// postcss.config.js (root directory)

module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
}
```

and finally just import the index.css into main.js and it works:

```
import '@/assets/styles/index.css' // global css (tailwind)
```